# How can I overwrite a column from a column in another table without a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to simply overwrite values in a column of a table with values from a column in another table.
I have a table based off from another table without a unique identifier in one of the columns, so I don't want to use joins, but just update the values since the rows are in the same order. How do I do that? So far I have tried two different approaches where Approach A only put the value from the first row into every row of the updated table whereas Approach B does not work at all.

```
Approach A:
Update Transactions
SET Transactions.Amount = Transactions_raw.Amount
FROM Transactions_raw


Approach B:
UPDATE Transactions
SET Amount = (SELECT Amount FROM Transactions_raw)
```

Comment: You should/must have an ID, your issue is the wrong design in the first place

Comment: SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  It is meaningless to say that the rows are in the same order, because there is no ordering to the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of `join` to match the tables -- even if on an artificial key:

```
update t
    set Amount = tr.Amount
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from Transactions t
     ) t join
     (select tr.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from Transactions_raw tr
     ) tr
     on t.seqnum  = tr.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that *the rows are in the same order* may mislead you. If you do `select` statement without `order by` and see **the same order** in both tables, this is not what you want rely on. This so called order is not guaranteed. Instead, you have to have some rule for ordering. When you have this rule, which you can place in `order by`, then you can add ID column to both tables according to this order.

You can calculate ID value using statement:

```
update Transactions 
set Id = row_number() over(order by ...)
```

Then you can use regular `inner join`.